# Linq Remove an uncommitted entity from an Entity Collection - How do you find the right one?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, telerik-grid, icollection

My RadGrid is populated from an entity framework ICollection held in Session State.  The primary key is an auto incremented field in the database.  A user can add multiple rows to the grid without submitting them to the database.  If the user removes a row before saving, how do you find the particular entity to remove?  So far, no primary key will be assigned to new rows until the data is actually saved.

```
DataContext context = (DataContext)Session["context"];

protected void rgEmployees_DeleteCommand(object source, GridCommandEventArgs e) {
    int MyID = Tools.GetInt((e.Item as GridDataItem).
        OwnerTableView.DataKeyValues[e.Item.ItemIndex]["My_ID"]);
    Employee ee= context.Employee.SingleOrDefault(t => t.ID == MyID); 
    // The problem with above line is that t.ID has not been established yet.
    context.Employee.Remove(ee);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the entities will be in the order you add them, I think your only option here is to do it by index i.e.

```
protected void rgEmployees_DeleteCommand(object source, GridCommandEventArgs e) {
    Employee ee = context.Employee.AsEnumerable().ElementAt(e.Item.ItemIndex); 
    context.Employee.Remove(ee);
}
```

Comment: The data does stay in the same order as what's shown on the grid and - with minor edits - this solution worked.

Comment: @Stoertz just bare in mind this code would bring your full `Employee` table into memory with `AsEnumerable`, there is no support for `ElementAt` with EF.